# Can't overwrite file on Windows

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, windows-7

Whenever I try to overwrite a file in Python 2.7 this is what happens, code:

```
a = open('hello.txt')
a.write('my name is mark')
```

And my error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mark Malkin\Desktop\New folder\opener.py", line 2, in <module>
    a.write('my name is mark')
IOError: File not open for writing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs on [`open`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open):

> If mode is omitted, it defaults to 'r'.

To write instead use,

```
a = open('hello.txt', 'w')
```

Or better yet,

```
with open('hello.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('my name is mark')
```

Comment: As soon as I get home to a Python IDLE I will try it.

Comment: worked after I did this: a = open('hello.txt', 'w') a.write("bla bla") a.close()

Comment: Can you do the same with microsoft word files?